# Keyboard issue on xUbuntu

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

For some reason, the @ and " are switched, so pressing Shift + 2 result in " instead of @ and vise versa. Also Shift + 3 result in £ instead of # and # is, for some reason, above the Enter button on my keyboard. Furthermore, while ~ should be above the Tab button in order to print it I have to input Shift + the key above Enter(that "normally" prints #). Is that intentional or not? And how can I switch the bindings to what I want?

Also, on my laptop I have Play/Pause, Fast Forward and Rewind buttons, that I could use (wohen I had Windows) while on any workspace to interact with Youtube (without opening it), and now they don't work. What can I do to make them work again?

Answer (score 0):

Have you perhaps selected an English UK keyboard instead of an English US keyboard to match your PC keyboard.
I have made this self-same error before and had similar results.

I found another question further down which relates to your question

Probably by switching from the English US keyboard layout to a layout of your choice. help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html – Gunnar Hjalmarsson Aug 27 at 21:04

My laptop is HP Omen HP-Laptop-15-dc0xxx I'm facing an issue that the symbol @ is achieved by clicking SHIFT+(double inverted comma symbol) and vice versa. Similarly for # symbol to be typed I need to press backslash symbol. How can I fix this?
keyboard keyboard-layout
share edit
asked Aug 27 at 20:33
Aman
1

```
2
Probably by switching from the English US keyboard layout to a layout of your choice. help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html – Gunnar Hjalmarsson Aug 27 at 21:04
```